# How to remap Enter to hyperkey (⌃⌥⇧⌘) when hold and to Enter when pressed?

Tags: keyboard

I am using Caps Lock → Hyper Key (⌃⌥⇧⌘) in Karabiner and it is working great.

However it's less comfortable to press keys that are on the left side of the keyboard, especially when the hand has a tendency to move one key column to the left to eliminate the pinky stretch. And if you are a touch typist then you are thrown off because your index finger is suddenly not on F but on D, etc. If you want your index finger to remain on F then you have to stretch your pinky, not talking about things like hyper + T or hyper + 5 or, etc.

How to make Enter work the similar way as Caps Lock (of course Caps Lock is also remapped to Esc on press but that is not important for now :)) ?